# Test Class giving error for Rest Web Service

Tags: apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getInvoices/*')

global with sharing class RESTInvoicesController {
      @HttpGet
      global static List<CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping> fetchCustomerInvoiceDue() {        
            String customerId = RestContext.request.params.get('customerId');  
            List<CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping> listToReturn = new List<CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping>();       
            for(CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping temp : CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails(customerId)){ 
                listToReturn.add(temp); 
            }                 
            return listToReturn;       
      } 
}
```

Following is the test class

```
@isTest

private class RESTInvoicesControllerTest{

        static testMethod void payR(){

             Account a=new Account(Name='King Tyres',Type='Dealer',Address__c='Ranchi',KUNNR__c='50002706');
            insert a;  

            Test.startTest();

            RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
            RestRequest req = new RestRequest();                                 
            req.httpMethod = 'GET';
            req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/getInvoices';
            req.addParameter('customerId', a.KUNNR__c);  
            RestContext.request = req;
            RestContext.response = res;
            List<CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping> invoiceDue = RESTInvoicesController.fetchCustomerInvoiceDue();              
            Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

When i run the test class it is giving the following error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object at this line

```
for(CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.CustomerOutStandingMapping temp : CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails(customerId)
```

Comment: What is `getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails` method doing?

Comment: the for loop you are mentioning itself doesn't have any possibility of null pointers, however, the function getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails might have. So you should dig up this method and see in the logs where is it getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

after you insert the account record in your test class, the only value staying on the variable a is the record id.

all other values will be null.

so you have to either query it back or store it somewhere else.

so in this line, you are effectively passing in null

```
req.addParameter('customerId', a.KUNNR__c);
```

which is what you are retrieving back in your Get method and passing it to the helper method..

may be store that in another variable to start with and use it during account creation and also reuse it even after you insert the account record

Comment: Even if i am hardcoding the value it is giving the same error

Comment: can you get the stack trace from the debug logs ?

Answer (score 0):

problem is with CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails(customerId).

Before using this in for loop, just prinnt in debug loga what it returns. It seems that CPORT_CustomerOutstandingAndLimit.getAllCustomerOutstandingDetails(customerId) returns null, that's why iterating over it in for-loop gives error.